# .text() concatenates strings without spaces when removing html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, concatenation

I have a rich text editor on my site and I am trying to create a reliable word counter for it.

Because it's a rich text editor it (potentially) contains html.

This html might be, for example:

```
<div class="textEditor">
  <h1><strong>this is a sample heading</strong></h1>
  <p><br></p>
  <p>and this is a sample paragraph</p>
</div>
```

To get a reliable word count I am trying to first convert the html to text using:

```
var value = $('.textEditor').text()
```

The problem I am facing is the string that is returned seems to concatenate where it removes the html tags and what I am left with is:

```
this is a sample headingand this is a sample paragraph
```

as you can see, the words 'heading' 'and' are joined to become 'headingand' which would give me a word count of 10 instead of 11.

any thoughts on how to properly achieve this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It looks  like the program is ignoring the whitespaces other than the SPACE. Might give a clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText):

```
var value = document.querySelector('.textEditor').innerText
```

or

```
var value = $('.textEditor')[0].innerText
```

```js
console.log(document.body.innerText)
```

```html
<div class="textEditor">
  <h1><strong>this is a sample heading</strong></h1>
  <p><br></p>
  <p>and this is a sample paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great - thanks Denys (slaps myself in the face for not thinking outside the jquery box :p )

Comment: Don't slap yourself too hard: innerText isn't really well known, for historical reasons (coming from Microsoft and deemed "non standard")

Comment: Also you can use `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` to removing additional space from string.

Comment: haha, I'll make it a soft slap... even though it's not too well known, I am assuming it is well supported?

Comment: @ronnieburns yes, all browsers support it

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of playing around with it and came up with the following:

```js
let value = $('.textEditor').text();
function read(){
    alert(value.trim().split(/\s+/).length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textEditor">
    <h1><strong>this is a sample heading</strong></h1>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>and this is a sample paragraph</p>
</div>
<button onclick="read()">Read</button>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOazqG?editors=1010

Just trim it and split and you should be fine.

Comment: Tip: When writing/editing a question about html/js/css, you should have a look at the snippet button in the toolbar

Comment: Thanks for the tips, was actually trying to accomplish that